# C++ vector.reserve() causing vector element to turn into 872456316

Tags: c++, vector

The following code outputs the unexpected value `872456316`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void){

  vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(3);
  v.insert(v.begin() + 1, 1); // Troublesome line 
  for(int i : v) cout << i << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Changing the troublesome line into `v.insert(v.begin(), 1);` causes the output to be `1`.

1. Why does this happen?
2. If the vector has reserved memory space for three `int`s, should there not be a way to assign a value to the second `int` before assinging a value to the first?

Comment: After `v.reserve(3)` your vector still has size 0.  Hence `v.insert(v.begin() + 1, 1)` results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: a parking place doesnt make a car ;)

Comment: Change `v.reserve(3);` to `v.resize(3);`.  Or change the other line to `v.insert(v.begin() + 0, 1);`.  Your "unexpected" value ought to have been an expected value, since any value (or crashing) could occur there. *If the vector has reserved memory space for three ints, should there not be a way to assign a value to the second int before assinging a value to the first?*  **Yes**, there should not — and indeed, there is not.  All is right with the universe.

Comment: vector.reserve just allocates memory but size remains unchanged & the memory is also uninitialized. You can print the size before and after reserve to double check & hence the undefined behavior. Reserve helps when you insert elements as there won't be allocation unless certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

`v` is empty so `v.begin()==v.end()`. `v.begin() + 1` is therefore an invalid iterator as you can't add to `v.end()`. This leads to undefined behaviour.

A vector is a contiguous container, there's no way to insert the second element before the first.

You can either do:

```
v.reserve(3);
v.insert(v.begin(), 0);
v.insert(v.begin() + 1, 1);
```

Or:

```
v.reserve(3);
v.push_back(0);
v.push_back(1);
```

Or:

```
v.resize(3);
v[1] = 1;
```

Or:

```
v.resize(3);
*(v.begin() + 1) = 1;
```

Or:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 1};
```

Or:

```
std::vector<int> v(3);
v[1] = 1;
```

Comment: Or declare it with the appropriate size.